# JForm::setFieldAttribute frontend vs backend usage

Tags: jform, com-fields

I'm missing something.  I've written a plugin to manipulate specific custom user fields (the new custom fields extension).  I create the fields, and make them required, but in /adminstrator I remove the required attribute using:

`$form->setFieldAttribute('fieldname','required','','com_fields');`

That part works great.

In my plugin, I also identify groups which will be relieved of the requirement in the frontend - but none of those attribute changes seem to stick.

If I print_r the $form variable before and after I make my change - I can see the change is made in the JFormXML object - but the form still displays the field as required.  I can add a class attribute and it shows up in the backend - but not the frontend.

I even went so far as to execute `$form->removeField('fieldname','com_fields')` and to my surprise, the field re-appeared at the bottom of the field group (from first to last)! There seems to be no way to modify these fields in the front-end....unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the frontend, FieldsHelper::prepareForm is run twice - a pull request has been issued to resolve this problem.

It should be resolved in 3.8.2 if the pull request is accepted and merged.

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/18211